# How to use propel as a default ORM in symfony

Tags: orm, symfony1, doctrine, propel

I am new to symfony,I want to create a application using Symfony framework using propel as ORM(Model),But I don't know to how to set Propel as a ORM instead of using Doctrine I just want to use propel alone.symfony has released new version with Doctrine as a defult ORM.So Please suggest how to change it to propel..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **Symfony 1.4**, quoting [the manual](http://www.symfony-project.org/getting-started/1_4/en/04-Project-Setup) :

> Configuring the database
>
> [...]
>
> If you want to use Propel instead of Doctrine, add `--orm=Propel` when
>   creating the project with the `generate:project` task. And if you don't
>   want to use an ORM, just pass `--orm=none`.

However if you want the last Propel version, I guess that you will have to install the **Propel15Plugin** (for details on how to install that plugin, see the *Readme* tab on the [Symfony Propel15Plugin page](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfPropel15Plugin)).

For **Symfony 2.0**, [this slideshow](http://www.slideshare.net/francoisz/symfony2-meets-propel-15-4) explains how to integrate Propel 1.5.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the Propel15 plugin - it's vastly superior to the bundled Propel and should be your default choice for new projects with Propel.

Comment: is there any possibility to integrate with propel1.6.0 or it supports only propel1.5?

Comment: In fact installing Propel15Plugin should install Propel 1.6 (last 1.x version), see this blog post http://propel.posterous.com/sfpropel16plugin-is-already-there-didnt-you-k